# Helper function for checking if we have a valid sudoku

Tags: c++

I am following a book called Elements of Programming Interviews and I am reading a helper function called `HasDuplicate` on page 79 and I am having trouble understanding how it works.

Here is the code:

```
// Return true if subarray partial_assignment[start_row]
// [end_row -  1][start_col, end_col - 1] contains any duplicate
// in {1, 2 ..., size(partial_assignemnt)}; otherwise return false.

bool HasDuplicate(const vector<vector<int>>& partial_assignment, int start_row, int end_row, int start_col, int end_col)
{
   deque<bool> is_present(size(partial_assignment) + 1, false);
   for(int i = start_row; i < end_row; ++i)
   {
       for(int j = start_col; j < end_col; ++j)
       {
           if(partial_assignment[i][j] != 0 && is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]])
             return true;
           is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]] = true;
       }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that partial_assignment is the partially filled sudoku grid. I am just not sure how it checks if there is duplicates. Perhaps it has something to do with the deque?

Comment: When is the sudoku invalid? I'm assuming when there are duplicate numbers in the same row or column right?

Comment: @lucieon Yes, I am just wondering how that function above checks for duplicates.

Comment: `is_present` represents an array-like with a flag for each possible _value_. The _value_ of `partial_assignment[i][j]` is used as index in `is_present` 1. to check if a value is present: `if (`... `&& is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]])` 2. to remark a value as present `is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]] = true;`.

Comment: The whole approach looks wrong to me but even before that, `is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]] = true` accesses an undeclared variable `j`.

Comment: Sorry guys see edits, mistake on my part

Comment: The deque isn't used as a queue at all here. It is being used as an array.

Comment: @TedLyngmo a set of small integers doesn't need a hash table, a simple array of booleans works better (it's like a hash table but the hash function is identity and there are no collisions).

Comment: @n.m. I agree. I wrote that comment a little too quick, but moved on and answered OP:s question later instead, but forgot to remove the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comments in the code:

```
bool HasDuplicate(const vector<vector<int>>& partial_assignment, int start_row, 
                  int end_row, int start_col, int end_col)
{
   // this creates a container for bookkeeping of used numbers
   // size+1 because the number 1-x are used.
   deque<bool> is_present(size(partial_assignment) + 1, false);

   // The variables i and j are used to go through every coordinate on the
   // sudoku game board.
   for(int i = start_row; i < end_row; ++i)
   {
       for(int j = start_col; j < end_col; ++j)
       {
           // here it checks if the current number is already marked as used in "is_present"
           // if it is, then it's a duplicate and the function returns true.

           // The value 0 is used at coordinates where no number has been
           // selected.
           if(partial_assignment[i][j] != 0 && is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]])
               return true;

           // otherwise, mark the number as used
           is_present[partial_assignment[i][j]] = true;
       }

    }
    return false;
}
```